# Change Shape in a different sheet if a cell is >95%

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the colour of multiple shapes on one sheet depending on the value of a cell in a different sheet. If the value is above or below 95% I'd like the shape to be coloured using RGB green or blue accordingly.

I am struggling to understand most other VBA scripts as they are either for the same sheet or for one shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it but probably the easiest way to explain is: lets say you have a sheet called Sheet1 and one called Sheet2. On Sheet2 you have a shape called Square. Your code might look like this:

```
Dim firstSheet as worksheet, secondSheet as worksheet

Set firstSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
set secondSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

If firstSheet.Range("A1") < 0.95 then 
     secondSheet.Shapes("Square").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If
```